# Still get 403 forbidden, after moved Apache root folder in /home directory and enabled config file?

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

I want to move root directory from **var/html/www** to **home/mitacheto/projects**, where "mitacheto" is mine username. What I already did:

1 - Opened `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and changed DocumentRoot, like this:

```
DocumentRoot /home/mitacheto/projects
```

2 - Added this to the end of the same file **etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**:

```
<Directory /home/mitacheto/projects>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3 - I changed Directory in etc/apache2/apache2.conf, so it looks like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/mitacheto/projects>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

4 - Finally I restarted the apache service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

When I open localhost, I got:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

Should I change permission of home/mitacheto/projects to 755?

Comment: Have you confirmed that AppArmor is not blocking Apache from accessing your `/home` directory?

Comment: @matigo How could I confirmed that ?

Comment: Assuming that AppArmor is running, you'll want to check the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2` configuration file 